# Найти в строке текст и заменить его на return функции

Tags: php

Есть строка вида

```
$str = 'Привет, это мой project(1, 10) проект';
```

Мне нужно чтобы там произошло выполнение функции:

```
function project($ot, $do) {
     .....
     return $res;
}
```

И соответственно чтобы в тексте было уже то что вернула функция.

P.S. эта строка выводиться из базы.

Хотелось бы что-то вроде:

```
str_replace('project(*), function project(*, *), $str)
```

Comment: Где ваш код, или хотя бы попытка это сделать самому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотрите в сторону [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Я думаю, это то, что вам нужно.

```
<?php

$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\s?)project\s?\(\s?(\d+)\s?,\s?(\d+)\s?\)(\s?)/ui', function($arr){return $arr[1] . project($arr[2], $arr[3]) . $arr[4];}, $str);
```

Comment: можно пожалуйста пример для моего случая?

Comment: обновил ответ. Посмотрите